# Obtain values from simulated mppm in spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

I have obtained an `mppm` object by fitting a model on several independent datasets using the `mppm` function from the `R` package `spatstat`. How can I generate simulated realisations of this model and obtain the `x`, `y`, and `marks` attributes of the simulations ?

I fitted my model as such:

```
data <- listof(NMJ1,NMJ2,NMJ3)
data <- hyperframe(X=1:3, Points=data)
model  <- mppm(Points ~marks*sqrt(x^2+y^2), data)
```

where NMJ1, NMJ2, and NMJ3 are marked `ppp` and are independent realisations of the same experiment.

`sim <- simulate(model)` allows me to generate simulated realisations of this model, and `plot(sim,axes = TRUE)` to plot them. `sim` itself is an `hyperframe` object:

```
> sim
Hyperframe:
   Sim1
1 (ppp)
2 (ppp)
3 (ppp)
```

How can I access the values (`x`, `y`, and `marks`) in this hyperframe ? My goal is to generate a large number of independent realisations from my model, and to use the simulated values for another task. Is there a practical way to obtain, retrieve and save these values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you want to simulate this many times I have here shown the code
with two simulations (rather than one as you have in the question):

```r
library(spatstat)
data <- list(amacrine, amacrine, amacrine)
data <- hyperframe(X=1:3, Points=data)
model  <- mppm(Points ~marks*sqrt(x^2+y^2), data)
sim <- simulate(model, nsim = 2)
#> Generating simulated realisations of 3 models..
#> 1, 2,  3.
```

Now `sim` is a `hyperframe` with 2 columns (one for each simulation). Each
column is a list of 3 point patterns. To get the three sets of coordinates
and marks for the first simulation use `as.data.frame` on each point pattern:

```r
co1 <- lapply(sim$Sim1, as.data.frame)
```

Then `co1` is a list of length 3, and we can print out the first few
coordinates with the `head()` command, e.g. the coordinates of the third
point pattern:

```r
head(co1[[3]])
#>           x         y marks
#> 1 0.4942587 0.7889985   off
#> 2 0.6987270 0.7637359    on
#> 3 0.3926415 0.6819965    on
#> 4 0.7982686 0.9060733   off
#> 5 1.3507722 0.9731363    on
#> 6 0.6450985 0.6924126    on
```

We can extract the coordinates and marks for each simulation by another `lapply` that
runs over every simulation (in this case 2):

```r
co <- lapply(sim, function(x) lapply(x, as.data.frame))
```

Now `co` is a list with 2 elements, and each element is a list of 3 sets of
coordinates:

```r
length(co)
#> [1] 2
length(co[[2]])
#> [1] 3
head(co[[2]][[3]])
#>           x          y marks
#> 1 0.1660580 0.04180501    on
#> 2 0.7840025 0.71727782    on
#> 3 1.2011733 0.17109112    on
#> 4 1.0429867 0.49284639    on
#> 5 1.1411869 0.86711072   off
#> 6 1.0375942 0.06427601    on
```

Comment: Thanks ! And I just have to replace `coords` with `marks` to obtain the simulated marks

Comment: Sorry! Forgot about the marks. They are returned together with coordinates if you use `as.data.frame` (which is a generic calling `as.data.frame.ppp`). I have edited the answer to reflect this.